# Grails Packaging and Naming Conventions

Tags: web-services, spring, grails, dependency-injection

Packaging Controllers, Services,etc. i.e. 
- com.company.controllers
- com.company.services

Is this a good practice or should be avoided by all means??

Another worth mentioning problem I encountered is in naming services Example

SomthingGatewayService.groovy can't be initialized in both these ways
- SomthingGatewayService somtinggatewayService
- def somtinggatewayService
I understand that the problem is in the 2 Capital Letters 'S'omthing and 'G'ateway before the conventional 'S'ervice, so its probably because of some sort of spring DI issue

So how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, putting Domain classes, services, controllers etc. into packages is a good idea IMO. Refactoring it later can be painful. Especially when dealing big applications or applications that grow over time.

Regarding the second problem: If you have a service called `SomthingGatewayService` then you'll be able to reference it by `def somthingGatewayService` (just the first letter is lower case).