# Grails package naming conventions

Tags: package, naming-conventions

I am new Groovy/Grails and I want to make sure I understand the naming conventions behind packages.

So since I work for a college whose website address is mssu.edu, my class names need to be edu.mssu.ClassName?

Also, what is the benefit of naming packages this way?

Comment: Related Link1:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721630/grails-packaging-and-naming-conventions

Related Link2:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743582/grails-and-groovy-metaclass-package-name-convention

Overview:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/package-summary.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with Grails - use standard Java conventions.